# How do I get in game sound out of the Xbox 360 to a soundcard if I play via a computer monitor that doesn't have audio output?

Tags: xbox-360

There are numerous guides on the internet but I still just can't figure this one out. I want to play the in game sound from a 360 Slim to a soundcard while using a hdmi display. What is the easiest way to do this, to output sound from a 360 to a soundcard if you are already using the hdmi port for a monitor that has no sound output.

I am using a Dell U2312hm monitor via HDMI, so the Xbox sends sound via HDMI but my Dell monitor has no audio output.

I see the 360 has a optical audio out. My soundcard has something called a S/PDIF in and output but the connectors aren't the same. The connectors on the soundcard looks like redwhite RCA connectors to me even though they say "SPDIF" (which is digital audio).

Here is a picture of the ports on my soundcard: [Here](http://www.pssl.com/images/Default-Image/1500/AUDIOFIRE-4.jpg).

So my only choice is to use the optical sound output from the 360 right. But with what kind of cable? My S / PDIF input on my soundcard is obviously a redwhite RCA connector which is what I don't understand. And the 360 Slim has a optical audio output.

Or can I just get in game sound through the controller? I need a 360 headset for that right? But I heard the controller only outputs chat and voice sounds, not in game sounds.

Does anyone here have experience with this?

Would highly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

There should be various option. Lets see how many i can list.

1. Use a hdmi -> hdmi/audio splitter [Something like this](http://www.gmaxtech.com/product/hdmi/HM-CV015/01.jpg)

This way you can use the optical spdif cable if there is any room for that in your pc. Or add the additional converter from answer 2

2. Use the right cable, altho i cant find any that fast on the internet as a whole cable you surely can find yourself a converter. The connection on your soundcard is known as a coaxial s/pdif while the one on your x360 is known as a optical s/pdif [explanation image](http://site.allaboutadapters.com/webgraph/ATC-Cables.gif)
3. Find any other connection that can suit Video and Audio like DVI/3,5mm or VGA/3,5mm (if the 3,5mm can work for you)

This might be a bit of a mess to understand but these are all i can think of right now.